# Custom date formatting in an NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsdateformatter

My app juggles historic events. Some event dates can be thousands of years BC. Obviously the dates for such events are not very accurate and end up in terms like "About 20,000 BC" or "Before 50,000 BC".

To tackle this, I have created a custom view which allows the user to build a custom date format when entering an event. This format is then stored - for later display purposes - with the date of the event as an instance of `NSString`. This all works quite well for views where I show one event per view.

However, when I want to display several events in an `NSTableView`, I'm stuck. I added a date formatter to the table cell in my `NSTableView` but there appears to be no way to bind my stored date format to the date formatter in the cell.

How can I achieve this? Bear in mind that the format string can be different for each row in the table...

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar requirement and haven't come up with a great solution yet, but I also haven't spent a lot of time trying.

What comes to mind, since it needs to vary on a row-by-row basis, is to make the formatter a property of your model object, then have a "meta formatter" on your table column that interrogates the objectValue and returns the result of applying the model's formatter to the model's data value.  (If that makes any sense at all...)

Edit: pseudo-code

In your custom NSFormatter subclass (the "meta formatter") you would implement something like:

```
- (NSString *)stringForObjectValue:(id)object {
    return [[object customFormatter] stringForObjectValue:[object date]];
}
```

In effect, the non-bound meta formatter acts as a proxy for the internally-represented per-row custom formatter.  Making it work with Core Data, well, you're on your own there. :-)

Comment: Would such a meta formatter not have the same problem? My app works with Core Data and uses bindings to retrieve and store data. Is the fact that NSDateFormatter does not expose bindings the crux of this?

Comment: While writing that comment, could I not just add a method to my Event object 'dateAsFormattedString' and bind my table attribute to that in stead of the date property...

Comment: You certainly could do that, and would have to make sure that the corresponding setter is properly implemented.  I don't use Core Data, so I can't comment specifically, but in general I would think that my approach should work. The meta formatter would *not* be bound to anything.  Will update comment in a moment...

Comment: Thanks, great idea. I'll give it a try. As for my 'dateAsFormattedString' idea, that would be a read only property which would do the transformation and requires no setter as it relies on the data already stored in the event. I wait a while, see what else comes up but will vote your answer up.

Comment: If you are binding and want the table to be editable, your formatter needs to be bidirectional AFAIK (bindings, by definition, are two-way).

Comment: But please follow up with your results - I have an interest in the best way to do this too!

Comment: Will do. In my case the table display is read only, so I would get away with it. The challenge with your solution is how to store an instance of NSDateFormatter in Core Data...

Comment: It might be more appropriate to store the configuration parameters of the formatter, then just initialize one using those parameters in the meta formatter.  This might allow you to be more efficient, too; formatters are comparatively expensive, so just keeping one around that you can compose as needed would be useful.